# Plotting - recursive

Tags: plotting

## Slightly clearer, hopefully:

I would like to plot Solve[Normal[Series[E^(n x), {x, 0, n}]] == 0 for incrementally increasing n, and show all plots overlayed. Here is my effort with up to n=63 using [this code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfg28ftpdokkwoh/code.txt):

[image]

...Very time consuming though, & I would really like to find a way of plotting it (& similar plots) up to any n without the labour-intensive copying & pasting.

Comment: Also, it's good to explain in words what you are doing instead of just posting a piece of code to decode first (!) and then improve.

Comment: Please see link to my other question for further details: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554964/roots-of-some-modified-bernoulli-polynomials

Comment: Thanks for the link. It would be useful to incorporate the relevant parts into this question so that users have the full picture here instead of having to follow links :)

Comment: There's an error in your statement.  You seem to be plotting `x/n`, not simply `x`.  Alternatively one can solve for the zeros of the partial sums for `E^(n x)`.

Comment: @ Michael E2, Thankyou very much :) - Yes, sorry for the error - forgot to mention rescaling:)

Comment: You might want to edit the question so that the detail about rescaling is not left only in a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way that's fast but inaccurate.  Some of the roots it finds for large `n` are wrong.

```
roots = Table[
    x /. NSolve[Normal[Series[E^(n x), {x, 0, n}]] == 0, x], {n, 200}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.441688, Null} *)
```

For accuracy set `WorkingPrecision` (a small amount will do), but it takes much more time:

```
roots = ParallelTable[
    x /. NSolve[Normal[Series[E^(n x), {x, 0, n}]] == 0, x, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 10], {n, 200}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {137.021271, Null} *)
```

To visualize, we convert the roots to points.  Packing the array is optional -- it will be packed when the graphics are displayed, if it is not pre-packed.

```
pts = Developer`ToPackedArray @ N[Flatten[roots] /. z_Real | z_Complex :> {Re[z], Im[z]}];
```

Here is the output on the more accurate calculation of the roots.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  GraphicsComplex[pts,
   {PointSize[Tiny],
    Dynamic @ Point[Range @ Length @ Flatten[roots[[;; n]]]]}],
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 1],
 {n, 1, Length @ roots, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate output]

The original `Manipulate` -- somewhat more straightforward but slower, as it converts the `roots` to points at every update:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{PointSize[Small], 
   Point[Flatten[roots[[;; n]]] /. z_Real | z_Complex :> {Re[z], Im[z]}]},
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 1],
 {n, 1, Length @ roots, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: @ Michael E2 - Great - I am getting slight problems with numerical error towards the end, but I can live with that! - Zeros should really be entering curve at all :)

Comment: Just out of interest, how would I increase the precision of the calculations? Have tried {Re[z], Im[z]},50], but doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Realise I will lose performance - just curious for static example.

Comment: `NSolve` has a `WorkingPrecision` option.  `WorkingPrecision -> 10` took 454 sec., but eliminated the points on x, y axes that encroach on the interior.  It's a good candidate for `ParallelTable`.

Comment: Great - thank you for your help on this :)

Comment: @martin You're welcome.  Thanks for pointing out the numerical errors in the first method.  I have a better pic now.  :)

Comment: Also, thanks for introducing me to ParallelTable :)